# Initialize array of characters using pointers

Tags: c, char

This problem is driving me crazy, I'm sure I'm missing something. I need to initialize an array of chars using only pointers. Below is the code I have so far:

```
    int p2(){
         /* Implements problem 2 of lab */

         // Create an array 
         char **s = (char**)malloc( 11 *sizeof(char));
         char *p = *s;
         char start ='A';

         while( p != s+10){
            *p = start;
            start++;
            p++;
         }

         return(0);
    }
```

The problem I'm having is I don't know how to address the characters inside of the array. I understand the base address of the array is **s, and the pointer to the first element is *s. What I don't understand is how to get to **s+10 (i.e. the end of the array).

Can anyone shine some light for me??? Please!

EDIT: Ok, looks like I misunderstood the question. I appears I need to create an array of strings (thus the char ** allocation). Then I need to loop through this array, and assign each string (i.e. char *) a value 15 chars long. Please let me know if I'm understanding this correctly:

char **strings ==> strings[0 ... n ] where each element is a pointer to a char (possibly an array). There for *string ==> strings[0], *(string+1) = strings[1], etc etc.

Am I close or way off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char **s` is 2 dimensional array of characters, or array of C strings if you want.
If you want to use array of characters you should use:

```
char *string = (char*)malloc( 11 *sizeof(char));
```

If you really want to initialize array of strings, at first step you're initializing array of pointers, that's:

```
char **s = (char**)malloc( 11 *sizeof(char *));
```

Please note that I'm using `char *` inside sizeof. Than when you may use strings, but at first you must initialize each string.

```
s[0] = (char*) malloc( 15*size(char)); // This is actually string, 14 characters long (NULL terminated)
char *p = s[0]; // p is pointer to beginning of your string now
```

And there's two way how to address your string:

```
s[0][3] // 4th character of your string
p[3]
```

Or if you want to use just pointers:

```
char *p = *(s+0);
*(p+3); // 4th character
*((*(s+0))+3) // To do it "hardcore"
```

**EDIT: added an example**

When you have `**char p` and use `p++` or `p + 1`, C increases memory address. `*p` operator tells compiler that you now want to work with data stored in memory, not with pointer. Therefor those two syntax do the same:

```
p[10] = 'a';
*(p+10) = 'a';
```

So if you want traverse both your dimensions, you should use:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    char *p = *(s+i);
    for( int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        *(p + j) = 'a'; // Say you wanna fill them with as
    }

    // You may also use this syntax:
    while( p < (*(s+i) + 10)){ // or use != instead of <
        *p = 'a';
        p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So how would you traverse the array (**s?). Would it be 

pCurr = *s;
while(pCurr != *(s+10)) {... pCurr++}

Comment: @certifiedNoob I've added traversing examples, hope they are helpful

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you meant this:

```
     char *s = (char*) malloc(11 *sizeof(char));
     char *p = s;
```

In which case you'd address the characters with `s[x]`

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need a `char **` unless you need an array of arrays.

Second, you can get to the end of the array with `(*s)[10]` or `*((*s)+10)`

Third, in C programming, don't cast the result of `malloc()`

Comment: ...Thanks for the 3rd line in your post.  Sadly, every other answer casts return of  `malloc`

Answer (score 1):

The code is falling apart here.

```
char **s = (char**)malloc( 11 *sizeof(char));
```

You're allocating enough memory for 11 `char`s, which sounds like what you want to do.

However, you're casting the address to those 11 `char`s to a `(char**)` as if you were allocating space for pointers, not `char`s.

Comment: Yes, I need to allocate space for 10 pointers to characters ( a character array, aka string). Then I need to loop through the array and assign values to though pointers. How would I address the pointers I've created in **s?

Comment: @certifiedNoob: A character array/string doesn't need 10 pointers to it.  One will do the job.  And that's what malloc is returning.  The one pointer to the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Why should you use a double pointer for creating an array of chars?

```
char *s = (char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
char *start = s; // save starting pointer

for(; s < start+10; s++)
    *s = 'a';

return 0;
```

If you allocate char ** essentially you're allocating an array of pointers to char(eg. array of strings). If you need char array, allocate char array. If you start working with pointers a design of stack and heap can be really helpful.